# Why does python require an initialized list before applying method?

Tags: python, list, initialization

The following works just fine:

```
b = [1,]
b.append([2, 3])
# returns type "list" [1, 2, 3]
```

But the following doesn't:

```
[1,].append([2, 3])
# returns type "NoneType"
```

This holds true for a few of the [list methods](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) that' I've tried. Why does Python require explicit variable declaration before applying a method?

Answer (score 2):

You're not reading that right. `.append()` returns None in both cases. In the first case, it is `b` that results in `[1, 2, 3]`. In the second, that list is created also, but you don't have access to it becaues you didn't assign a variable name to it.

Comment: *facepalm* Thanks for pointing that out, wasn't checking return types.

Answer (score 1):

**append** returns **None** as its value, but alters the list.  Try

```
b = [1,]
output = b.append([2, 3])
```

You'll get **None** for **output**, too.